# PrismaClientInitializationError: Error in connector: Error creating a database connection VScode

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, express, prisma

Facing this issue for the last 2 days, tried every possible solution e.g reset cache, flushing dns, and everything that could reset ports, reinstalled VScode but nothing seems to work [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B52Hk.png)

The same connection string works when connecting without using prisma client [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikY9m.png)

Here is the connection string in .env file

DATABASE_URL="mongodb+srv://alpha:alpha@cluster0.3fpvyik.mongodb.net/testing"

Even works with another project in which I am not using prisma [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UusbZ.png)

When trying to introspect, its giving this error! [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBHzM.png)

Comment: I don't see a port in your connection string and the [docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/database-connectors/mongodb#connection-url) mention that the default is 27017 while your error message says 27019.
Also what is `+srv` the docs just say `mongodb` as the connector. Look in the link I posted and try to follow exactly as it says the connection string should look `mongodb://USERNAME:PASSWORD@HOST:PORT/DATABASE?ssl=true`

Comment: I tried this but it gives another error which says incorrect connection string format, when you see the getting started docs https://www.prisma.io/docs/getting-started/setup-prisma/start-from-scratch/mongodb/connect-your-database-typescript-mongodb

Comment: DATABASE_URL="mongodb+srv://test:test@cluster0.ns1yp.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase"
this is the connection string format mentioned there

Comment: What about the port, did you try adding it to your connection string?

Answer (score 1):

you are working with **prisma** in .env file format of DATABASE_URL should be like this if using **mongodb Atlas ** follow the steps:
1.in database choose connect the select "connect to application"
2.copy the url and past it as ** DATABASE_URL** in .env file for example

```
mongodb+srv://zeta:<password>@zetaapplication.kciyn8z.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

3.remove everything after mongodb.net / and replace by your database name like below

```
mongodb+srv://zeta<password>@zetaapplication.kciyn8z.mongodb.net/your_db_name
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your DATABASE_URL in your .env file and make sure your database url is not inside a " ". if it is, remove the " at both sides.